# Can’t click on login button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having trouple to click on the login button please see attached images for my code:
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eakj3.png)

Comment: Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question, especially the part about providing an MCVE. Posting code as an image is a no no. Please remove the image and replace it with your code as text, properly formatted. Also please add the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code line.

```
WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login"));
loginbutton.click();
```

Comment: The code you entered will raise an error. The `click()` does not return a `WebElement`. Also I don't see the point in clicking the button twice. Especially since the first click will probably redirect the user to a different page which means the second page will throw a `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Comment: @RemcoW I'm assuming it was a simple oversight... I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something simple like

```
driver.findElement(By.id("loginLink")).click();
```